# How to check if the type is device or emulator?

Tags: windows-10

I want to conditionally check device type runtime for windows 10 UWP. there is already a class and enum available for windows phone 8 platform as mentioned below.

> Class - Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType
>
> Enum - Microsoft.Devices.DeviceType

What is equivalent for windows 10 platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [this](http://igrali.com/2014/07/17/get-device-information-windows-phone-8-1-winrt/) approach. The classes are available for UWP as seen on [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation)

```
private static EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = new EasClientDeviceInformation();


public static bool IsRunningOnEmulator
{
    get
    {
        return (deviceInfo.SystemProductName == "Virtual");
    }
}
```